# Uploading image on codeigniter , shows error :The upload path does not appear to be valid

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I am using php codeigniter Framework, and trying to upload image in the folder & shows in the profile view but here is what i get when i upload the file :-

```
 Array (
    [upload_path] => ./community/photos/
    [allowed_types] => jpeg|jpg|png
    [max_size] => 100
    [max_width] => 1024
    [max_height] => 768
    [overwrite] => 1
    [file_name] => 1600052487_Musical-Birthday-Candle-Magic-Lotus-Flower-Candles-Blossom-Rotating-Spin-Party-Candle-14Small-Candles-2layers-Cake.jpg
 )
```

**The upload path does not appear to be valid.**

**profile.php controller**

```
public function do_upload()
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($_FILES);
        //die;
        if(!empty($_FILES['filename']['name'])){ 
            $config['upload_path']          = FCPATH.'application/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpeg|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 100;
            $config['max_width']            = 1024;
            $config['max_height']           = 768;
            $config['overwrite']            = true;
            $config['file_name']            = time().'_'.$_FILES['filename']['name'];

            print_r($config);
                        //echo var_dump(is_dir(FCPATH.'uploads/'));

            //die;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('filename')) 
            {
                //echo "sdfs";
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
                die;
                   // $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Invalid Credentils');
                redirect('myProfile');
                 //   $this->load->view('admin/profile/index', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                echo "xcvcx";
                die;
                    $data = array('user_profile' => $this->upload->data());

                    $this->load->view('admin/profile/index', $data);
            }
        }else{
            echo "dfgfd";
        }
    }
```

**index.php view**

```
<h2 class="heading">Profile</h2>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="profile-img">
                 <?php if (!empty($user->photo)): ?>
               <img src="/uploads/<?php echo $user->photo; ?>" alt="<?php echo $user->photo; ?>">
                  <?php endif;?>
                  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS52y5aInsxSm31CvHOFHWujqUx_wWTS9iM6s7BAm21oEN_RiGoog" alt=""/>
                  
                 
                 <?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/profile/do_upload');?>

                 <div class="file btn btn-lg btn-primary">
                     <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                      <input id="choose_image" type="file" name="filename" />
                </div>
                <button id="SubmitBtn" type="submit" style="display:none">Upload photo</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

**autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database','session','form_validation','encryption','upload');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form', 'file');
```

I have tried several solution but still getting the same error .

Comment: How come you have $config['upload_path']= FCPATH.'application/' but your print_r($config) shows ./community/photos/.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Linux?

Comment: I added ./community/photos/. to see if it solves the issue and it did not so removed it . I am using mac

Comment: Ok so where does ./community/photos reside in terms of your file structure?

Comment: You might have to set your file permissions on your community/photos folder as 0775 or similar.

Comment: I actually dont know that , how can i find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try to put initializes the CI file upload class before doing do_upload? .

i usully use this one

```
 $this->upload->initialize($set_upload);//my func class for config
   //generally they use $this->upload->initialize()
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')){


        }
```

Comment: I Added and now getting an error :The upload destination folder does not appear to be writable

Comment: try to change path with this $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/'; @RoxanaSlj

Comment: Great,I successfully uploaded the photo in my uploads folder , but still not displaying on view

Comment: no, i mean close this question. but ok. if your photo that uploaded to the folder not diplaying in the view, so the problem is 1. the controller, 2. your url img, check it @RoxanaSlj

Answer (score 0):

I thinks  uploaded path should be "./application"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (!empty($user->photo)): ?> 
<img src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/'.$user->photo;);?>" alt="<?php echo $user->photo; ?>">
 <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: what problem you are getting? can you get broken image or not? check its path by open image in new tab.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but mine was a typo error.

Instead of using this

```
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

I accidentally used this due to copy and pasting

```
$this->load->initialize($config);
```

It took me several hours to figure this out. I hope I helped someone.